# React-Sidebar: Button is unclickable when moved outside props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to modify the first example given in the [react-sidebar](https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar) documentation by moving the location of the button outside of the props.children. When I do this, the button becomes unclickable. The button doesn't not just do anything, it actually can't be clicked.

It seems like the z-index from the sidebar is taking up the full screen even when it is collapsed, but when i set the button's z-index to 3 it is still unclickable.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Sidebar
        sidebar={<b>Sidebar content</b>}
        open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
        onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
        styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
      >
        <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>
          Open sidebar
        </button>
      </Sidebar>
    );
  }
```

My non-working modification:

```
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <Sidebar
        sidebar={<b>Sidebar content</b>}
        open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
        onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
        styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
      />
        // Moved button out of here
       </Sidebar>

      <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>
        Open sidebar
      </button>

     </div> 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because [react-sidebar](https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar) has an overlay which is covering the entire screen and the button is falling beneath it, because of which you can't click the button. Just give the button `position: absolute` and `z-index: 4` or so and it will become clickable and will work.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. That wouldn't be a great solution anyway because that means the button would be displayed on top of the sidebar & overlay at all times.

Comment: Actually just changing the z-index for me worked.....navbar-toggler {

  z-index: 4;
}

Comment: But it only worked for the button...it is sstill blocking the other links in the navbar....can't we just remove that overlay?

Answer (score 0):

The given answer doesn't work. What worked for me was setting the overlay's height and width to zero. Using Developer Console, you can find the CSS selector for the overlay, which, for me was `#gatsby-focus-wrapper > div:nth-child(1)`. So, the code that fixed the issue was -

```
#gatsby-focus-wrapper > div:nth-child(1){
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```